# dpath.utils: TypeError:object of type class has no len()

Tags: python, typeerror, pickle, dpath

I have a path. Using dpath-utils, I create a dictionary by creating sub-keys according to path length. But in the current example my path length is short as below.

***notes*:**
if it were long path: 
"/cbghb6b2861f919f6ffc238a0c5cffed63436/bbc238a0c5cffed6343fc238a0c5cffed63436". I explained this because this is the reason I used dpath.utils

I add the path to the corresponding key of the dictionary by using dpath.utils as below.

```
model_dict = {}
path = "/b6b2861f919f6fc238a0c5cffed63436"
data= {
        'metadata': {
                          'author': None, 
                          'column_name': [...], 
                          'date': datetime.datetime(20...1, 870998), 
         'metrics': {...}, 
         'name': None, 'source_code_version': None}, 
         'model': <src.python.ml.optis...10f4695f8>
        }
 }


dpath.util.set(model_dict, path, data)
```

```
model_dict = {
             'b6b2861f919f6fc238a0c5cffed63436':{
                    'metadata': {
                          'author': None, 
                          'column_name': [...], 
                          'date': datetime.datetime(20...1, 870998), 
                    'metrics': {...}, 
                    'name': None, 'source_code_version': None}, 
                    'model': <src.python.ml.optis...10f4695f8>
                   }
             }
```

```
dpath.util.get(model_dict, path)
```

but I get this error when calling with path.

**Output:**

```
 File "/Users/****/Documents/**/src/python/ws/***/restful/**/**.py", line 30, in get_model
    return dpath.util.get(self.persisted_file , path)
 File "/Users/*****/.virtualenvs/*****/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dpath/util.py", line 171, in get
    results = dpath.segments.fold(obj, f, [])
  File "/Users/****/.virtualenvs/******/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dpath/segments.py", line 349, in fold
    for pair in walk(obj):
  File "/Users/******/.virtualenvs/*******/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dpath/segments.py", line 62, in walk
    for found in walk(v, location + (k,)):
  File "/Users/*****/.virtualenvs/*******/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dpath/segments.py", line 62, in walk
    for found in walk(v, location + (k,)):
  File "/Users/******/.virtualenvs/********/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dpath/segments.py", line 48, in walk
    for k, v in kvs(obj):
  File "/Users/*****/.virtualenvs/****/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dpath/segments.py", line 16, in kvs
    return zip(range(len(node)), node)
TypeError: object of type 'RegressionModel' has no len()
```

but when I call directly, there is no problem but I don't want to call directly. because I might want to get the value in one of its subkeys. and how low this is.

```
model_dict.get("b6b2861f919f6fc238a0c5cffed63436")
```

**Output:**

```
{
        'metadata': {
                          'author': None, 
                          'column_name': [...], 
                          'date': datetime.datetime(20...1, 870998), 
         'metrics': {...}, 
         'name': None, 'source_code_version': None}, 
         'model': <src.python.ml.optis...10f4695f8>
        }
 }
```